# Non Eu family member travelling to Ireland

Tags: uk-residents

I am living in Madrid, Spain, with a wife who is working here in Madrid too. I want to go to Ireland to visit as a tourist but without her. I have a Spanish residence permit of family member of the EU.  Can I travel to Ireland without applying for Visa or what is it exactly I need to do? Do I need other travel documents to travel alone?

Comment: What is your citizenship (you’ve tagged your question ‘uk-residents’, not sure why)?  You can check the entry requirements for the Republic of Ireland here http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/check-irish-visa

Comment: @Traveller For some reason I can't fathom, that official web site doesn't seem to cover the situation of traveling with an Article 10 residence permit. It is covered [elsewhere](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/visa-eu-family-residence-card) on the site though.

Answer (score 3):

The general rule is that you can use your "family member of a Union citizen" Article 10 residence permit to travel without a visa, if you are traveling with or joining the EU citizen family member.

This is [documented](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/visa-eu-family-residence-card) on Ireland's official web site:

> Your EU/EEA or Swiss family member has [rights under EU treaties](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/EU+Treaty+Rights) that may allow you to accompany or join them in Ireland without a visa.
>
> To exercise this right, you must apply for and hold a 'Residence card of a family member of a Union citizen' of the type referred to in [Article 10 of Directive 2004/38/EC](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2004:158:0077:0123:en:PDF).

If you wish to travel alone, you will need to obtain a visa.